# Looping through all Combo boxes on a VB form

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, controls

I am making a grade application for a school project and I am wondering how I can loop through and check a value in all combo boxes on a certain form, I have 19 units to check; trying to be efficient without making 19 case statements. I have tried an array and me.controls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
For Each c As Control In Me.Controls.OfType(Of ComboBox)()
    'You cann acces to ComboBox her by c
Next
```

Comment: Ah when I tried typeof I made an additional variable as cmb, I had the right idea but wrong syntax. I will post my old code when I have access to it.

Comment: Will do, I was asking this question as I had to leave class thinking I had enough time.

Comment: Please mark the answer if is it correct, Thank you!

Comment: For Each Me.all_Cmb In Me.Controls
            If TypeOf (all_Cmb) Is ComboBox Then
                Select Case all_Cmb
                    Case "U"
                        grade_Score += 0
                        grade_Point += 0 Case "P"
                        grade_Score += 7
                        grade_Point += 70
                    Case "M"
  Etc...

Comment: Please can you explain what do you want do with combobox ?

Answer (score 1):

Note that if you have controls host by containers (TabControl, SPlitPanel, etc.) you may not find all of your controls.

Here is a recursive call that should return all of your controls:

```
Sub GetControlList(container As Control, ByVal ctlList As List(Of Control))
    For Each child As Control In container.Controls
        ctlList.Add(child)
        If (child.HasChildren) Then
            GetControlList(child, ctlList)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

I have on occasion had problems with the controls on SplitContainer panels so if you use a splitter make sure you are getting all your controls.

Once you have a complete list of controls you can operate on them. This sample is working with DataGridView controls:

```
Dim ctrls As New List(Of Control)
GetControlList(Me, ctrls)
For Each dgv As DataGridView In ctrls.OfType(Of DataGridView)()
    AddHandler dgv.DataError, AddressOf DataGridView_DataError
    Debug.Print(dgv.Name)
Next
```

FYI the generic data error code:

```
Private Sub DataGridView_DataError(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs)
    Dim dgv As DataGridView = sender
    Dim sGridName As String = dgv.Name.Replace("DataGridView", "")
    Dim col As DataGridViewColumn = dgv.Columns(e.ColumnIndex)
    Dim sColName As String = col.HeaderText
    MsgBox(sGridName & vbNewLine & "Column " & sColName & vbNewLine & e.Exception.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
End Sub
```

Comment: I made a couple simple code edits. The edit in 2nd sample was just for brevity, but the edit in the 1st sample sometimes confuses people. You really do want `ByVal` instead of `ByRef` here. Please test it to see that it really does work this way before reverting. In .Net, the difference between ByRef vs ByVal is whether it's making a _copy_ of the reference or using the _same_ reference, but it's still the _reference_ that gets passed either way. So passing a reference type like List or Control ByVal still works the way you want, and it's usually the more correct option.

Answer (score 1):

You already have the `OfType(OF T)` method. You use it like this:

```
ForEach box As ComboBox In MyForm.Controls.OfType(Of ComboBox)()

Next
```

But this only checks the *direct* children of your control. If you have container controls like GroupBox, Panels, FlowControlLayoutPanel, etc, you'll miss the controls nested inside them. But we can build a new `OfType()` method to search these recursively:

```
Public Module ControlExtensions
    <Extension()> 
    Public Iterator Function OfTypeRecursive(Of T As Control)(ByVal Controls As ControlCollection) As IEnumerable(Of T)
        For Each parent As Control In Controls
            If parent.HasChildren Then
                For Each child As Control In OfTypeRecursive(Of T)(parent.Controls)
                    Yield child
                Next child
            End If
        Next parent

        For Each item As Control In Controls.OfType(Of T)()
            Yield item
        Next item
    End Function
End Module
```

And you use it the same way:

```
ForEach box As ComboBox In MyForm.Controls.OfTypeRecursive(Of ComboBox)()

Next
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to check containers for controls of the type you're looking for, here's a little function that should do the trick for you.

```
Private Function GetControls(Of T)(container As Control, searchChildren As Boolean) As T()
    Dim Controls As New List(Of T)

    For Each Child As Control In container.Controls
        If TypeOf Child Is T Then
            DirectCast(Controls, IList).Add(Child)
        End If

        If searchChildren AndAlso Child.HasChildren Then
            Controls.AddRange(GetControls(Of T)(Child, True))
        End If
    Next

    Return Controls.ToArray()
End Function
```

Here's the usage, if search children is True then all child containers will be searched for the control you're looking for. Also, for the top most container we'll just pass in Me assuming you're calling the code from within your Form, otherwise you could pass the Form instance or a specific Panel, GroupBox, etc.

```
Dim ComboBoxes As ComboBox() = GetControls(Of ComboBox)(Me, True)
```

Comment: This is the hard way. There's already an OfType(Of T) method on the Controls collection.

Comment: I wrote the code to be compatible with .NET 2.0 since he didn't specify his requirements.